# How to trigger http 1.1 4xx 5xx error code? c#

Tags: c#, web-services, http, restful-authentication

How do have your application response with a http 1.1 4xx 5xx error in c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Throw an `HttpException` with the appropriate `HttpStatusCode`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx

Example:

```
throw new HttpException((int) HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented, "Requested function not supported");
```